# Comparing nested list of list with a list

Tags: scala

I am trying out to compare list of list values with another list and return if matched.I am looking it in scala however i am new into scala and it difficult to do if any suggestions please pass on

```
val l1 = List(List(1,12.34,76.456,12,List(1,2,3)),List(2,12.43,76.256,12,List(11,12,13)))

val l2 = List(1,2,3,12)
```

so here trying to compare `l1([1,2,3])` with `l2 [1,2,3,12]` and `l1 [11,12,13]` with `l2 [1,2,3,12]` and return if not matched any elements from l1 to l2.

here we are looking for of l1 any value matched with l2 then 0 else 1

Tricky but is it doable in scala?Any suggestions

Comment: what is the data structure?  You mentioned list values. is this supposed to be a Map? The data structure as you described it does not make much sense.

Comment: From your given input, what is the expected output? Please add this to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the initial set of requirements that you have provided, the following solution will solve your problem

```
val l1 = List(List(1,12.34,76.456,12,List(1,2,3)),List(2,12.43,76.256,12,List(11,12,13)))

val l2 = List(11,12,13)


l1.flatten.filter(_.isInstanceOf[List[Int]]).map(x =>
  if(x == l2) 0 else 1)
```

This gives you a result whether the list l2 matches inner list of l1 or not.

```
res1: List[Int] = List(1, 0)
```

Comment: It should give [0,1] since l1 contains 2 main list.Second one matched so 1 and others 0.

Comment: @AshwinKumarPadhy the solution has been modified.

Comment: Thanks Chaitanya.Its working.Will it be same if the input is string.

Like val l1 = Array("o1,12.73,77.65,[1,2,3]#o2,12.73,77.65,[1,2,3]#o2,12.73,77.65,[1,2,3]")

what changes is required

Comment: The solution will change for different types of inputs. If this solution answers your question you may please accept it

Comment: @AshwinKumarPadhy you can post a different question for that

Answer (score 0):

You need to flatten `l1`. to make it generic (because as I understand, `l1` can be list of list of list..) you can create a generic method which flatten it:

```
def flatten[T](l: List[T]): List[T] = l match {
  case Nil => Nil
  case (x: List[T]) :: tail => flatten(x) ::: flatten(tail)
  case x :: tail => x :: flatten(tail)
}
```

Then, you can get the result it by:

```
(l2.map(flatten(l1).contains)).map(_.compare(false)) // List(1,1,1,1)
```

Here is the code to run and debug - https://scalafiddle.io/sf/3SStZZX/1